# rewriting python dictionary in a different order

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary which a have to reorganize the data in a different representation.

current_dict:

```
{
"1384": { 
    "Calcium": {
        "0-20": {
            "id": 2079 
        }
    }
},
"1387": {
    "Calcium": {
        "0-20": {
            "id": 1798
        }
    }
},
"1397": {
    "Calcium": {
        "0-20": {
            "id": 1586
        }
    }
}
```

So I have to reorganize this dict grouping the elements Calcium, its inner deeps and ids and also the outer ids in the following representation:

desired output:

```
{
"Calcium": {
    "0-20": [
        {
            "Area_id": 1384,
            "Intepolation_id": 2079
        },
        {
            "Area_id": 1387,
            "Intepolation_id": 1798
        },
        {
            "Area_id": 1397,
            "Intepolation_id": 1586
        }
    ]
}
```

How exactly can I accomplish that?
In addition, could you recommend me what should I study to understand better how to create this kind of algorithms? I've been trying to fix this problem for quite some time and all the examples I find on internet about dicts are pretty vague and basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
dct = {
    "1384": {"Calcium": {"0-20": {"id": 2079}}},
    "1387": {"Calcium": {"0-20": {"id": 1798}}},
    "1397": {"Calcium": {"0-20": {"id": 1586}}},
}


out = {}
for k, v in dct.items():
    for kk, vv in v.items():
        for kkk, vvv in vv.items():
            out.setdefault(kk, {}).setdefault(kkk, []).append(
                {"Area_id": int(k), "Interpolation_id": vvv["id"]}
            )

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "Calcium": {
        "0-20": [
            {"Area_id": 1384, "Itnterpolation_id": 2079},
            {"Area_id": 1387, "Itnterpolation_id": 1798},
            {"Area_id": 1397, "Itnterpolation_id": 1586},
        ]
    }
}
```